# "No resource found..." trying to compile a blank cross-platform Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using VS Community 2015, Update 3. I installed Xamarin v4.2 via the VS installer, then updated via a Xamarin installer to 4.2.1.60.

I created a new Cross-Platform project: `Blank App (Xamarins.Forms Portable)`. I set the Droid project as Startup Project, and then right click on BlankApp1.Droid to try and compile the Android project.

I am getting the following compile errors: (errors are in file `styles.xml`)

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowActionModeOverlay'.

Styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Packages Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

The project is set to compile using the latest Android version = 6.0.

I also updated Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package from 2.2.0.45 to 2.3.2.127. I get the same list of errors (although, strangely the errors are in a different order...)

Any ideas of what the problem is and how to solve?

Comment: Have you tried clearing down the project and rebuilding?  A restart of Visual Studio may also help

Comment: Could you post the content of `packages.config` file? I believe you do not have correct version Android Build tools and Android SDK tools installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips
```

Locate this zip file:

```
2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip
```

Now delete this file, then go back to Visual Studio and Rebuild Solution.. will take some time to fully download the file depending on your connection speed, it's around 200mb.

Comment: Indeed, that solved the problem! Thank you. The existing file was only 9 MB.