# No resource found that matches the given names

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'll build a Xamarin application but when I start the build for the Android project, The compiler gives me 9 errors:

> **9 errors:** No resource found that matches the given names:
>
> 1. `attr windowNoTitle`
> 2. `attr colorPrimaryDark`
> 3. `attr windowActionBar`
> 4. `attr windowActionModeOverlay`
> 5. `attr colorAccent`
> 6. `attr colorPrimary`
> 7. `attr colorAccent`
> 8. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`
> 9. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

**Notes:** The Errors happens in the file `styles.xml` in the `Project.Droid` project.

Here you can find the `styles.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

I've nothing changed in the `SmartBox.Droid` project but got this errors. Could the problem happen because I've added a `MainPage.xaml` and a `Map.xaml` in the `SmartBox (Portable)` project? I need two pages because I'll navigate between the two pages.

I've searched everywhere on Google and SO but found no solution that helps me. My source code you could find on GitHub (https://github.com/HeinPauwelyn/SmartBox) in the folder Execution → SmartBox

Comment: check my answer here, if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672135/no-resource-found-trying-to-compile-a-blank-cross-platform-xamarin-app/40682583#40682583

Comment: No, it didn't solve the errors I've got. Also after restarting VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this solution:

1. Update your Xamarin to the latest version (both shared project and your platform project).
2. Then redirect to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\` and rename the `Xamarin` folder to `Xamarin_old`.
3. Reopen your project, and build it. It will take a few minutes until the packages are fully downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the following lines in your `Tabbar.axml` and `Toolbar.axml` inside the Resources/Layout folder. This worked for me.

**Tabbar.axml**

From:

```
android:background="@style/colorPrimary"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
```

To:

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
```

**Toolbar.axml**

From:

```
android:background="@style/colorPrimary"
```

To:

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

Comment: No I'm sorry the code don't help for me. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I used the project in your github.. and it compiles fine, still got the same errors?

Comment: Yes exactly the same. I'll also say, I use android version 4.4.2 _(KitKat API 19)_ device Huawei Y540-U01

Comment: I have Compile version: API 23, Minimum: API 15 & Targeted: Compile Version (API 23). Running on a Samsung Note 5.